# Block hidden (dot) php files

Tags: nginx

I want to block access to hidden `.dot` files, specifically `php` files in Nginx, but I can't find a solution. 
`.ht` files are hidden by default which is specified in following:

```
location ~ \.ht {
        deny all;
}
```

I wrote this rule to match all files starting with `dot` but it's not working:

```
location \.(.+\.*)(.*)\.(.+\.*)(.*)$ {
        deny all;
}
```

Here are some examples of files that should be hidden

```
/.foo.php
/path/to/.foo.php
```

What should I do?

Comment: // Regular expressions are specified with the preceding “~*” modifier (for case-insensitive matching), or the “~” modifier (for case-sensitive matching). // see nginx.org/r/location

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to look carefully at the order of your `location` blocks. This location:

```
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}
```

should match any URI with a path element beginning with a `.`.

However, it needs to be place **above** any other regex location block. Also, any prefix location block using the `^~` modifier will take precedence.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

*Note also: The location blocks in your question are both wrong. The first one will also match `index.html` and the second one is missing the `~` modifier for a regex location.*

Comment: To expand on this, Nginx processes the most specific location block that applies to each request. Have a read of this http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, putting `location` block aboce other regexes did the job.